# Get total sum of video comments for each video

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sum

I have a table video

```
videoId | channelId | commentCount
a       | 1         | 5
b       | 1         | 3
c       | 2         | 1
```

and a table channel.
video.channelId maps to channel.Id

```
Id
1
2
3
```

For every videoId I need the commentCount and the sum of all commentCounts for that channel.

So the end result should be:

```
videoId | channelId | commentCount | commentCount_sum
a       | 1         | 5            | 8
b       | 1         | 3            | 8
c       | 2         | 1            | 1
```

My code so far:

```
SELECT v.videoId, v.channelId, v.commentCount, SUM(v.commentCount) commentCount_sum
FROM videos v
JOIN channels c
ON c.Id = v.channelId
GROUP BY v.videoId
```

but I don't get the correct commentCount_sum for each videoId - commentCount_sum is the same as commentCount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has supported window functions for over a year, and that seems to be what you want:

```
select v.*,
       sum(v.commentCount) over (partition by v.channel_id) as commentCount_sum
from videos v;
```

For your question, there is no need to `join` to `channels`.  However, if you need to, you can add that to the query.

Comment: This assumes the OP's version of SQLite be recent and supports analytic functions.

Comment: My version is recent and up-to-date. Your code works, thanks a lot. I'll read about window functions for a better understanding of your code.