# Get comments per video and total sum of comments per video channel

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count, sum

In addition to [Get total sum of video comments for each video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59426317/get-total-sum-of-video-comments-for-each-video) I noticed that I can't use v.commentCount because I cleaned some data and now the column is inaccurate.

So I need to count the videoId comments and the total videoID comments with the comment table.

I have a table video

```
videoId | channelId
a       | 1        
b       | 1        
c       | 2
d       | 2
```

and a table comments.
video.channelId maps to comments.videoID_channelID

```
   commentID | replyID | videoID | videoID_channelID | textOriginal
   c1        | NULL    | a       | 1                 | "test"
   c2        | NULL    | a       | 1                 | "some text"
   NULL      | r1.c1   | b       | 1                 | "asdad"
   NULL      | r2.c1   | b       | 1                 | "xxx"
   c5        | NULL    | b       | 1                 | "yyy"
   c6        | NULL    | c       | 2                 | "zzz"
   c7        | NULL    | d       | 2                 | "-...-."
```

For every videoId I need the commentCount (how many comments are there per videoId) and the sum of all commentCounts for that channel (how many total comments are there for every video of a channelID?).

So the end result should be:

```
videoId | channelId | commentCount | commentCount_sum
a       | 1         | 2            | 5
b       | 1         | 3            | 5
c       | 2         | 1            | 2
d       | 2         | 1            | 2
```

My code so far:

```
SELECT v.videoId,
        v.channelId,,,
        count(c.textOriginal) commentCount,
        count(c.textOriginal) over (partition by c.videoID_channelID) as commentCount_sum,
FROM videos v
JOIN comments c
ON v.videoId = c.videoID
GROUP BY v.videoId
ORDER BY commentCount_sum ASC
```

but I don't get the correct commentCount_sum?

Comment: What is `sentiment_sum` and `textOriginal`? Edit your question and explain what you want.

Comment: Edited. text = textOriginal, sentiment_sum was another column, I now count over c.textOriginal because c.* is forbidden. I just need the single video commentCount und the aggregated channel commentCount per video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate in a subquery, and then do a window count in the outer query:

```
select t.*, sum(commentCount) over(partition by channelId) commentCount_sum
from (
    select v.videoId, v.channelId, count(*) commentCount
    from video v
    inner join comments c on c.videoID = v.videoId and c.videoID_channelID = v.channelId
    group by v.videoId, v.channelId
) t
```

I also fixed your join conditions (you were missing a join condition on `channelId`).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=231f9316e68950c79de9e1fc15121b0b)**:

```
videoId | channelId | commentCount | commentCount_sum
:------ | :-------- | :----------- | :---------------
a       | 1         | 2            | 5               
b       | 1         | 3            | 5               
c       | 2         | 1            | 2               
d       | 2         | 1            | 2
```

Comment: I use SQLite version 3.30.1 and get "misuse of window function count()" in row 1.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
SELECT v.videoId,
        v.channelId,
        count(c.textOriginal) commentCount,
        (select count(c.textOriginal) from comments d where d.videoID_channelID = v.channelId group by d.videoID_channelID) as commentCount_sum,
FROM videos v
JOIN comments c
ON v.videoId = c.videoID
GROUP BY v.videoId
ORDER BY commentCount_sum ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without using `window function`... I have them spaced out see you can see what exactly we are doing. As GMB pointed out, you were missing a join on channelID.

```
select a.*, b.channel_comment_count
from 

  (select v.videoid, v.channelid, count(c.textoriginal) as video_comment_count
   from cte1 v join cte2 c on v.videoid = c.videoid and v.channelid = c.videoid_channelid 
   group by v.channelid, v.videoid) a

  inner join

  (select channelid, count(c.textoriginal) as channel_comment_count
   from cte1 v join cte2 c on v.videoid = c.videoid and v.channelid = c.videoid_channelid 
   group by v.channelid) b

  on a.channelid=b.channelid
```

**OR**

```
 with cte as
(select v.*, c.textOriginal from cte1 v join cte2 c on v.videoid = c.videoid and v.channelid = c.videoid_channelid)

select a.*, b.channel_comment_count
from 
    (select videoid, channelid, count(textoriginal) as video_comment_count
    from cte group by channelid, videoid) a
    inner join
    (select channelid, count(textoriginal) as channel_comment_count
    from cte group by channelid) b
    on a.channelid=b.channelid
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f1bd09dae68c59cce2d418c73ab6545e)